# copy .evt file from one PC to another using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have copied the .evt file from event viewer and placed it in a folder named BkEvt. Now I have to copy the content of the folder (.evt files) to **another PC** which sharing the same Vlan using a batch file. I used the below script but it did not function:

```
@echo off 
copy c:\P3.\Documents and settings\mms\Desktop\BkEvt\file.evt \\P4.\d$\BkEvt
```

P3. is the source PC name and P4. is the destination PC name where i want to copy the file into.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @echo off 
 copy "c:\P3.\Documents and settings\mms\Desktop\BkEvt\file.evt" \\P4.\d$\BkEvt
```

This uses the default administrative share on P4. You have to have admin rights to use it.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have edited my script because the BkEvt folder is from my desktop. Anyway, I tried your script but it does not work. Any other idea? I have the admin rights for this PC

Comment: Did you specify the filename for the copy? Look at the edit and structure it that way.

Comment: Yes I specify the file name but still it did not get copied to the other PC. Il edit my script on top

Comment: Does the BkEvt folder exist on D: on P4.?

Comment: Yes the BkEvt folder exist on D: on P4.

Comment: I'm at a loss. Your servers really have .'s in their name? What happens when you try the copy? Any error messages?

Comment: Nevermind. I see now that you have spaces in your path. put quotes around it and it should work.